# GPG asks for Passphrase for new key

Tags: macos, gpg

I want to know what to do after forgetting a passphrase. I've deleted and revoked all keys and made a new one but I was hoping that the passphrase would reset for me. to make a newer one. Do I need to uninstall the application to reset passphrase? If I'm wrong please do correct me and help me figure this out.

Comment: The passphrase is unique to each secret key. If you have made a new key pair then you should have been asked for a new passphrase during creation.

Comment: That doesn't apply to me. There is a window(Pinentry Mac) that opens which i have to enter the passphrase but everytime a open a new key it keeps opening the same window. I haven't got to chose which passphrase to put for the newer key.

Comment: It does apply to you.  You cannot reset a passphrase.  If you have forgotten it then you have lost access to your encrypted data.

Comment: How does it apply to me when i just said that GPG doesn't let me create a passphrase after making a new key?

Comment: This looks like a Pinentry thing on Mac.